# Using jQuery, how do I pinpoint the specific class out of several

Tags: jquery

Thought this would be an easy script, but I am stumbling on something

Reference attached image. [image]

See #panels-ipe-paneid-1436 {#1} from there 
I want to add a class to {#2}, the “.panel-separator” and ONLY that “panel-separator”
Then I will do a .css({"font-family":"AGaramondPro-Bold","font-size": "25px","padding-bottom": "20px;"}); on the combined classes

When I do get to add a class to next occurrence of “panel-separator” it adds the new class to several, if not to all, of the occurrences of “panel-separator”.

I have used next() and prev() and parent().find() and closest(), there is something, obviously, that I am missing.

This to me, should work, but no go:

```
jQuery('#panels-ipe-paneid-1436').closest('.panel-separator').addClass( "newClsHere" );
```

Could someone assist with ->Using jQuery, how  do I pinpoint the specific “panel-separator” that occurs after #panels-ipe-paneid-1436

Comment: You repeatedly mention “.parent-separator” but I don't see it in your image. What about `$('#panels-ipe-paneid-1436 > div.panel-separator').css({"font-family":"AGaramondPro-Bold","font-size": "25px","padding-bottom": "20px;"})`?

Comment: please show your code, how you are trying to do so.

Comment: so sorry j08691 - i meant "panel-separator", that is the #2 shown in the image.

Comment: Umer Hayyat : here are some of the scripts i tried:
jQuery('#panels-ipe-paneid-1436’).parent().find( '.panel-separator' ).addClass( “newClsHere” );

 jQuery('#panels-ipe-paneid-1436').parent().find( '.panel-separator' ).css('margin-bottom', '100px !important');

 jQuery(‘#panels-ipe-paneid-1436').next( '.panel-separator' ).addClass( "newClsHere" );

jQuery('#panels-ipe-paneid-1436').parent().next( '.panel-separator' ).addClass( "newClsHere" );

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Also, `.closest()` looks UP the DOM, not down.

Comment: HI j08691 - I did try your, but that did not work.  I could see in the DOM, that something happened, but the css was not applied to the panel-separator class div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got this thing to work.  See code below.

```
jQuery('#panels-ipe-paneid-1436').next('.panel-separator').addClass( "new-get-info-cls-here" );
jQuery('.panel-separator.new-get-info-cls-here').css('height', '1px');
```

I guess it was just better to do it in two steps